# Generics and ViewModels in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to simplify this following code with generics. Instead of conditional unwrapping for a type inside each of ChildViewOne, ChildViewTwo and ChildViewThree, can I achieve the same with generics?

```
struct UserInfo {
  let name: String
  let image: UIImage
}

enum SomeType {
  case typeOne
  case typeTwo
  case typeThree
}

struct ParentViewModel {
   let userInfo: UserInfo
   let type: SomeType

   var contentViewModel: Any {
    switch type {
      case .typeOne:
           return ChildViewModelOne(name: userInfo.name, type: type)
      case .typeTwo:
           return ChildViewModelTwo(image: userInfo.image, type: type)
      case .typeThree:
           return ChildViewModelThree(image: userInfo.image)
   }
}

struct ChildViewModelOne {
  let name: String
  let type: SomeType
}

struct ChildViewModelTwo {
  let image: UIImage
  let type: SomeType
}

struct ChildViewModelThree {
  let image: UIImage
}
```

ParentViewController will be injected with ParentViewModel.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
  let viewModel: ParentViewModel

  init(viewModel: ParentViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(bundle: nil, frame: nil)
  }

  // other required initializer

  func configureViewForType() {
     // Logic to handle subviews - ChildViewOne, ChildViewTwo & ChildViewThree
  }
}
```

This is what I tried so far:
I introduced a protocol ConfigurableView

```
protocol ConfigurableView {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    func configure(model: ViewModel)
}

class ChildViewOne: UIView, ConfigurableView {
    func configure(model: ChildViewModelOne) {

    }

    typealias ViewModel = ChildViewModelOne
}
```

**Update**

How do I return this from ParentViewModel as a `contentViewModel` object in ParentViewModel? `contentViewModel` is to be called from `func configureViewForType()` inside `ParentViewController` where based on the `type` value inside ParentViewModel, I load the correct `ChildView`

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Let's talk about the "this" that you are trying to achieve. What's the purpose of the parent view model and three children? The children seem to have nothing in common, and the parent fails to unify them (which is why you are asking this question, no doubt). How are you planning to have the single view controller deal uniformly with this diversity? Is it supposed to have one instance of each of them simultanously as its three children?

Comment: They are not meant to be unified. Based on the `type` in `ParentViewModel` I add the correct `ChildViewModel`. At any point in time there can be only one ChildView inside the ParentView as a subview. The idea here is to reuse the capabilities of ParentViewController and subview have its own configuration. I can even imagine a case where Generics is not required here.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. If they are not meant to be unified, what is ParentViewModel _for_?

Comment: And also, how is the view controller going to get visible content onto the screen when each child view model is a totally different kind of thing?

Comment: During the lifecycle of ParentView, there will be only one ChildView added. Based on ParentViewModel's type, we load the correct `ChildView` ChildView have their own model which ParentViewModel computes and returns

Comment: I still don't see the parent as needed. What the view models have in common, as far as the view controller is concerned, is the `configure` method. So (and I think you've already gotten this far) all we need is one protocol that requires a `configure`, and three structs that conform to it. Behold the dependency injection. The parent and the generic are both red herrings.

Comment: Got it sir :) So shall i just stick to Dependency Injection and remove `contentViewModel` from ParentViewModel.

Comment: Can I say if the childViews conform to `ConfigurableView` protocol, the childViews ViewModels are created inside `func configureViewForType()` in ParentViewController and then configured?

Comment: I'm just saying that it sounds to me like, as far as the view controller is concerned, it has a dependency conforming to ConfigurableView protocol. Now give that protocol all the requirements that the view controller needs to know about, and now any struct can conform to it and satisfy the dependency. I don't know who you want to _do_ the injection or _when_ the injection takes place; that's a higher level architectural issue, and depends on how this view controller is used, I suppose.

Comment: Just a good link to see: https://academy.realm.io/posts/doios-natasha-murashev-protocol-oriented-mvvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A View Model is not actually a "ViewModel". That idea is pervasive because not all languages have nested types. Instead, it is a `View.Model`.

```swift
class ChildViewOne: UIView {
  struct Model {
    let name: String
  }

  init?(model: Model, coder: NSCoder) {
    self.model = model
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  private let model: Model

  required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I say a ViewModel should only care about the data and not about how it is being drawn in the View? Do you thinking having a property in  `struct  Model` that returns the NSAttributedString is reasonable?

Comment: @DesperateLearner "Do you thinking having a property in struct Model that returns the NSAttributedString is reasonable" that's totally acceptable.